# Vetur can't find package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, package.json, vetur

I was writing code for my app with Vue and everything worked perfectly. Then I started to create child components and I could not refresh the localhost anymore.

Now it says:

**"Vetur can't find 'package.json"**
&
**"Vetur can't find 'tsconfig.json' or 'jsconfig.json"**

and when I try to "npm run serve" in the cmd - then i get this:

```
C:\Users\cmana\Desktop\WebDeveloper\Vue app\vuetify-todo>npm run serve
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\cmana\Desktop\WebDeveloper\Vue app\vuetify-todo\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\cmana\Desktop\WebDeveloper\Vue app\vuetify-todo\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cmana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-07T12_03_13_953Z-debug.log
```

Acording to this https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/setup.html#project-setup - I tried to add the jsconfig.json file with this content. (I deleted all the child components so I only have these vue files (About, Todo, App) left.)

```
{
  "include": [
    "./src/views/About.vue",
    "./src/views/Todo.vue",
    "./src/App.vue"
  ]
}
```

Still nothing. Anybody any ideas? Thank you <3

Comment: Ok I solved it. There were two problems.

1) I inserted into workspace folder that was not my root folder. (it was one level above.) So i removed it and then i inserted the root folder. Then it was finaly able to find the package.json.


2) I created the `jsconfig.json` in my source folder and not in the root folder again... So I moved it there and it worked...

Answer (score 14):

First of all, in Visual Studio code, type:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

This command, will open this window

[image]

Type: **settings json** in search bar, like this:

[image]

Open the first option: "**Open Settings (JSON)**".

Now, on JSON file, add this: `"vetur.ignoreProjectWarning": true,` in the end of file, like this:

[image]

Restart Visual Studio Code and you're done!

Comment: Thank you sir. Perfect.

Answer (score 10):

Installing the EsLint extension should solve your problem

if you are on VS Code, search for the EsLint extension by publisher:"Dirk Baeumer", install it and approve the installation to start the EsLint server

Alternatively run this in the terminal
`npm install eslint` in your workspace

The package.json file gets modified and your server will be up again

for further information on the EsLint extension you can check
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Good luck!

Comment: npm install eslint is the only solution that helped me!

Answer (score 5):

Add **"vetur.config.js"** outside your project.

In this example below, **"vetur.config.js"** is added outside the project **"vueProject"**:

[image]

Shrinking **"vueProject"** looks clearer:

[image]

Then, paste this code below to **"vetur.config.js"**:

```js
// vetur.config.js
/** @type {import('vls').VeturConfig} */
module.exports = {
  // **optional** default: `{}`
  // override vscode settings
  // Notice: It only affects the settings used by Vetur.
  settings: {
    "vetur.useWorkspaceDependencies": true,
    "vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true
  },
  // **optional** default: `[{ root: './' }]`
  // support monorepos
  projects: [
    './packages/repo2', // shorthand for only root.
    {
      // **required**
      // Where is your project?
      // It is relative to `vetur.config.js`.
      root: './packages/repo1',
      // **optional** default: `'package.json'`
      // Where is `package.json` in the project?
      // We use it to determine the version of vue.
      // It is relative to root property.
      package: './package.json',
      // **optional**
      // Where is TypeScript config file in the project?
      // It is relative to root property.
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
      // **optional** default: `'./.vscode/vetur/snippets'`
      // Where is vetur custom snippets folders?
      snippetFolder: './.vscode/vetur/snippets',
      // **optional** default: `[]`
      // Register globally Vue component glob.
      // If you set it, you can get completion by that components.
      // It is relative to root property.
      // Notice: It won't actually do it. You need to use `require.context` or `Vue.component`
      globalComponents: [
        './src/components/**/*.vue'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In VS Code, if the actual code is in a subfolder (e.g you have a monorepo), you can add a `vetur.config.js` in the root directory as per below.

```
module.exports = {
    projects: [
      {
        root: './frontend', // root of your vue project (should contain package.json)
        package: './package.json', // Relative to root property, don't change this.
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',  // Relative to root property, don't change this.
      }
    ]
  }
```

Please refer to [Vetur Reference](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/reference/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

in VSCode

ctrl + p 
open setting.json 
add this line:

```
  "vetur.ignoreProjectWarning": true,
```

this will ignore the error.

Comment: Also thank you. Your help is appreciated. :)